# Flask send_file as attachment no response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I coded a jQuery with flask where on-click it should perform an SQL search and export the dataframe as excel, the script is:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function () {
    $('a#export_to_excel').bind('click', function () {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + ' /api/sanctionsSearch/download', {
            nm: $('input[name="nm"]').val(),
            searchtype: $('select[name="searchtype"]').val()
        }, function (data) {
            $("#download_results").text(data.result);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

However there was not response on the browser, my python code is as below:

```
from io import BytesIO,StringIO
from flask import render_template, request, url_for, jsonify, redirect, request, Flask, send_file

def index():

#get the dataframe ready and define as 'data', parameters obtained from form input in html

name = request.args.get('nm','', type = str)
type = request.args.get('searchtype','Entity',type = str)

#function get_entity() to get the dataframe
#I have checked and the dataframe is functioning properly
data = get_entity(name,type)

#check if the dataframe is empty
if data.empty == True:
    print("its not working bruh...")
    word = "No results to export! Please try again!"
    return jsonify(result = word)

#store the csv to BytesIO 
proxy = StringIO()
data.to_csv(proxy)
mem = BytesIO()
mem.write(proxy.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))

mem.seek(0)
proxy.close()

print("download starting....")

#send file
send_file(mem, as_attachment=True,attachment_filename='Exportresults.csv', mimetype='text/csv')
word = "Download starting!"
return jsonify(result = word)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? The "download starting..." was properly printed to the html but the download did not start at all.

Comment: You must initialize an application context in Flask. `app = Flask(__name__)` and perform all these actions in an app route `@app.route('/')` which should render your html page or make an AJAX call. Finally, you should call this with `if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(debug=True)`. This will display any Traceback errors in the console when the app runs. Please paste that traceback error here.

Comment: I did initialize an application in my original code, I have activated the debug and there were no traceback errors, the html responded properly by changing #download_results according to the python code.
    #("#download_results").text(data.result)

The only problem is the download did not start

Comment: ok I have solved the problem now, solution is not ideal but it will do

Comment: You may add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not ideal, but what I did is adding a window.open(url) command in the jquery which will call another function, this function will send_file to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should use return statement

```
return send_file()
```